# Non-class type error on invocation of a member class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've got a strange problem on invoking a class member function.
I built a class to handle IPsec connections using Netlink. This class takes a config object as constructor argument which again constructs with custom IPAddress objects. The address objects are constructed by a string wich contains the actual IP address.
Then I invoke a member function of the IPsec class which adds an SA (also using a config class).

What I can't explain is the compiler error when invoking the said function to add the SA:

```
std::string svsrc, svdst, spsrc, spdst, spdev;
svsrc="10.0.0.1";
svdst="10.0.0.2";
spsrc="10.0.0.3";
spdst="10.0.0.4";  
NetlinkIPsecManager ipsmgr(IPsecConfig(IPAddress(svsrc),IPAddress(svdst),IPAddress(spsrc),IPAddress(spdst)));
ipsmgr.addSA(SAConfig(keyfield,"aes",1234));
```

This yields the following error message:

```
request for member 'addSA' in 'ipsmgr', which is of non-class type 'NetlinkIPsecManager(IPsecConfig (*)(IPAddress, IPAddress, IPAddress, IPAddress))'
```

I can't really explain this error, but the really strange part follows, as this actually works:

```
std::string svsrc, svdst, spsrc, spdst, spdev;
svsrc="10.0.0.1";
svdst="10.0.0.2";
spsrc="10.0.0.3";
spdst="10.0.0.4";    
NetlinkIPsecManager ipsmgr(IPsecConfig(IPAddress(svsrc),IPAddress(svdst),IPAddress(spsrc),IPAddress("10.0.0.4")));
ipsmgr.addSA(SAConfig(keyfield,"aes",1234));
```

**The only difference is the "hardcoded" IP address in the last argument of the constructor instead of a string variable.** If not set "hardcoded", the result is the unability to use any member functions. This only concerns the member functions, though. The construtor itselfs runs fine with the last argument as variable.

If this wasn't strange enough, it also works with string objects if I just instantiate named objects for my config and IP address member classes instead of using nameless ones inside the constructor call.

```
svsrc="10.0.0.1";
svdst="10.0.0.2";
spsrc="10.0.0.3";
spdst="10.0.0.4";
IPAddress vsrc(svsrc);
IPAddress vdst(svdst);
IPAddress psrc(spsrc);
IPAddress pdst(spdst);
IPsecConfig ipc(vsrc,vdst,psrc,pdst);
NetlinkIPsecManager ipsmgr(ipc);
ipsmgr.addSA(SAConfig(keyfield,"aes",1234));
```

So, this last example also runs just fine. As this is a practicable workaround for me, this isn't a big problem, but I just want to know if anybody has an *idea* what's going on here.
I find this behavior very strange and I'm curious what the problem might be.
So, does anybody know what C++ is trying do (wrongly) do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ipsmgr` has been declared as a function that returns a `NetlinkIPsecManager` and takes as an argument a pointer to a function that returns a `IPsecConfig` and has 4 `IPAddress` parameters.

```
NetlinkIPsecManager ipsmgr(IPsecConfig(IPAddress(svsrc),IPAddress(svdst),IPAddress(spsrc),IPAddress(spdst)));
^return             ^name  ^return     ^param1   ^name  ^param2   ^name  ^param3   ^name  ^param4   ^name
```

The constructor calls look like you're declaring a named function parameter. If you wrap one of the arguments in parentheses the problem will go way.

Comment: Thanks, that explained why the first example doesn't work and your suggestion with parentheses solved the problem. Why my second example with the direct string as last parameter also worked, though, remains yet a mystery to me...

Comment: @Marste a string literal cannot be mistaken for a type name or a parameter name, so there is no ambiguity; it has to be a constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

You have discovered the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  Just extract the single parameter to the constructor (the one whose own constructor takes four parameters) out into a separate variable which you then pass in--that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that explained a lot (+1). Taking the single parameter out doesn't work though, as C++ still interprets this as a function call (and produces the error `no matching function for call to...`. What works is unravel all of the paramaters as in the last example or using parentheses as in the second answer. Thanks a lot for the explanation.